# Sorting filenames by numeric fields (substrings)

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a set of files in a folder A1, with the following naming convention :

```
MCU1_0001_01 
MCU2_0002_01 
MCU1_0001_02 
MCU2_0002_02
MCU1_0003_01
MCU2_0003_02
```

The 4 digit value in the middle continues to increment until the value of 34, whereas the value that follows after MCU alternates between 1 and 2 and so does the last two digits at the end of the string.

That being said, 
I wanted to sort these files according to the middle value first, then the value at the end of the string, second. 
Note, I also am not interested in sorting the value that follows "MCU".

How can I do that?

this is what i've been trying

```
ls MCU[12]_00[0-9][0-9]_0[12] sort -t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split fields on `_` and sort by fields `2` to `3`:

```
$ ls | sort -t_ -k2,3
MCU1_0001_01
MCU1_0001_02
MCU2_0002_01
MCU2_0002_02
MCU1_0003_01
MCU2_0003_02
```

See [`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) for description of `-t`/`--field-separator=SEP` and `-k`/`--key=KEYDEF`.

---

If your fields are not zero-padded, you want to use `-n` for numeric sort:

```
sort -t_ -k2n -k3n
```

(this sorts by numeric value of second field, and then by numeric value of third field). To debug how `sort` interprets fields, run with `--debug` flag.